# Does spring CrudRepository support deleteBy of a list?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Does the Spring Data `CrudRepository` provide deletion of a list of entries by a attribute that is not the primary key?

```
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    public void deleteByName(List<String> names);
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes this is possible, the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.1.RELEASE/reference/html/) explains the `In` keyword with the following example. It is further shown by the example that the list argument does not have to be of the type of the primary key of the entity:

`In` -> `findByAgeIn(Collection<Age> ages)`

> `In` and `NotIn` also take any subclass of Collection as parameter as well as arrays or varargs.

and this in turn could then be applied to your delete query:

> In addition to query methods, query derivation for both count and delete queries, is available.

Something like:

```
void deleteByNamesIn(List<String> names);
```

Answer (score 3):

Deletion by attribute that is not a primary key is possible.
For the list argument I think that you are looking for the `in` operator, so try following:

```
void deleteByNamesIn(List<String> names);
```

*(Another little comment I might add: Methods defined in interfaces are public by default because private methods inside an interface declaration would make little sense. So in my opinion it is good style to drop the `public` here)*